# Bindable variable cannot assign to other variable

Tags: apache-flex

Why the value of productitem.idProduct cannot assign to the variable Ai?

```
        [Bindable] public var productitem:Object;

public function dataGrid_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                var Ai:int = productitem.idProduct;

            getAllPorductstatushistoryResult.token = porductstatushistoryService.getAllPorductstatushistory();
            getPorductitemhistoryProductIDResult.token = porductstatushistoryService.getPorductitemhistoryProductID(Ai);
        }
```

and the error pile is

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

```
at productDetailComp/dataGrid_creationCompleteHandler()[C:\Users\School\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\FYPadminSideV3\src\productDetailComp.mxml:153]

at productComp/productdataGridItemSelect()[C:\Users\School\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\FYPadminSideV3\src\productComp.mxml:56]

at productComp/refreshApp_product()[C:\Users\School\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\FYPadminSideV3\src\productComp.mxml:73]

at productComp/___productComp_Group1_creationComplete()[C:\Users\School\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\FYPadminSideV3\src\productComp.mxml:9]
```

and line 153 is the line

```
var Ai:int = productitem.idProduct;
```

line 56 is the line

```
pC.dataGrid_creationCompleteHandler(e);
```

line 73 is the line

```
    productdataGridItemSelect(e);
```

which is part of the

```
        protected function productdataGridItemSelect(event:GridSelectionEvent):void
        {

            ProductDetailComp.productitem=productdataGrid.selectedItem;

            var pC:productDetailComp = new productDetailComp();
            var e:FlexEvent;
            pC.dataGrid_creationCompleteHandler(e);

        }

        public function refreshApp_product( ):void{

            //var productdataGrid:Object;

            //productdataGrid.selectedIndex = 5;

            productdataGrid.selectedIndex = 0;



            var e:GridSelectionEvent;


            productdataGridItemSelect(e);



        }
```

The first problems is Why the function stop there? and other problem is "productdataGrid.selectedIndex = 0;" not working and not pre-select any dataGrid. Is there any other method to make it work?

Comment: Well, `productitem` is `null`. You try to access a property of an instance that doesn't exist.

Comment: There is part I don't understand. I can use such as productitem.productName, productitem.manufactor... in the mxml part to make the variable bindable to other compenent's variable, but I cannot use it in the script??

Comment: Yes and no. The difference is that a binding (whichever method used) will swallow any errors thrown when the binding is executed. So when the binding is executed on `productitem.productName` while `productitem` is `null`, this will throw the same TypeError (1009) internally, but it will be swallowed, so your application doesn't crash. Note that `var Ai:int = productitem.idProduct` is not a binding; that's just setting a variable.

Comment: So, how can I make it work? Getter and Setter seem not working because the orginal value of productitem is cased by flex as Object. I run out of method can change the data type of the orginal value.

Comment: I see no reason why a getter/setter pair wouldn't work.

Comment: my action scirpt's logic have problems. So, the variable always return error while doing the casting. =.='